# How To Show Category in Drop-down and Hide if Not Available in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am working with drop-down in Django, and I have done this. But main issue is this if a `category` doesn't have `subcategory` then drop-down should be hide, Please let me know how I can do it.

here is my `html` code when I am displaying `category`, `subcategory` and `subchildcategory`..

```
   {% for i in cat %}
                            <li class="mega" id="hover-cls"><a href="javascript:void()" class="has-submenu" id="sm-15980957729343015-21" aria-haspopup="true" aria-controls="sm-15980957729343015-22" aria-expanded="false">{{i.cat_name}}
                                <span class="sub-arrow"></span></a>
                                <ul class="mega-menu full-mega-menu" id="sm-15980957729343015-22" role="group" aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="sm-15980957729343015-21" aria-expanded="false">
                                    <li>
                                        <div class="container">
                                            <div class="row">
                                                {% for j in i.subcategoryies.all|slice:"0:10" %}
                                                <div class="col mega-box">
                                                    <div class="link-section">
                                                        <div class="menu-title">
                                                            <h5>{{j.subcat_name}}<span class="according-menu"></span></h5>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="menu-content" style="display: none;">
                                                            <ul>
                                                               {% for k in j.SubChildRelated.all %}
                                                                <li><a href="/subcategory/{{k.slug}}">{{k.name}}</a></li>
                                                                {% endfor %}
                                                            </ul>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                {% endfor %}
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
 {% endfor %}
```

here `{% for j in i.subcategoryies.all|slice:"0:10" %}` subcategory will display, but if `{{i.cat_name}}` doesn't have `subcategory` then it should not be display as a dropdown in main menu, so please let me know how I can hide the dropwown if a category doesn't have subcategory.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `length` filter for the `SubChildRelated` and check if it is > 0.

Example code:

```
    {% for i in cat %}
                                <li class="mega" id="hover-cls"><a href="javascript:void()" class="has-submenu" id="sm-15980957729343015-21" aria-haspopup="true" aria-controls="sm-15980957729343015-22" aria-expanded="false">{{i.cat_name}}
                                    <span class="sub-arrow"></span></a>
                                    <ul class="mega-menu full-mega-menu" id="sm-15980957729343015-22" role="group" aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="sm-15980957729343015-21" aria-expanded="false">
                                        <li>
                                            <div class="container">
                                                <div class="row">
                                                    {% for j in i.subcategoryies.all|slice:"0:10" %}
                                                    <div class="col mega-box">
                                                        <div class="link-section">
                                                            <div class="menu-title">
                                                                <h5>{{j.subcat_name}}
                                       // MODIFIED LINE BELOW
                                                                    {% if j.SubChildRelated|length > 0 %}<span class="according-menu"></span>{% endif %}
                                                                </h5>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="menu-content" style="display: none;">
                                                                <ul>
                                                                   {% for k in j.SubChildRelated.all %}
                                                                    <li><a href="/subcategory/{{k.slug}}">{{k.name}}</a></li>
                                                                    {% endfor %}
                                                                </ul>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    {% endfor %}
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                    {% endfor %}
```